# ETIAS mandatory or not?

Tags: schengen, etias

[One page](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/etias-wont-be-mandatory-until-2023-official-sources-confirm/) says ETIAS is optional until 2023, but another page says we must have it to enter Finland and another one says mandatory to go to any Schengen country.  Sorry I've forgotten where the other two are, but they were either government or well-done tourism pages (not bloggers of unknown reliability but still could be wrong).

What's the scoop?

Comment: Your (official) source says the same thing that I quoted.  But again, other sources say it’s mandatory without giving a future date.  Your site does seem official, thus an appropriate _answer_

Comment: It's now expected to be operational in 2024: https://travel-europe.europa.eu/etias_en

Comment: They want to make sure that everything works correctly, smoothly and without large delays in extrem situations such as found in ports. [2023-01-17: EU biometric border system faces more delays - BBC News](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-64311737)

Comment: postponed to May 2025.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This page from the EU](https://travel-europe.europa.eu/etias_en) is the current official reference on the topic. It states:

> ETIAS is currently not in operation and no applications are collected at this point.
>
> Starting from mid-2025, some 1.4 billion people from over 60 visa-exempt countries are required to have a travel authorisation to enter most European countries.

ETIAS is expected to start operations in mid-2025. Once it starts, there will be a first 6-month grace period, which is pretty loose, and another, which will be a lot more restrictive.

(edited to reflect the yet-again postponed date)

Comment: I’m so accustomed to seeing websites that should have been updated and weren’t.  A bit surprising to see more than one that makes a statement two years _before_ it’s true.

Comment: That page is no longer accessible, and implementation has been delayed yet again, this time until sometime in 2024.  https://travel-europe.europa.eu/etias_en

Answer (score 4):

ETIAS is designed to be mandatory for visa-exempt third-country travellers for short-term visits. Your first link doesn't really contradict this. It simply says a grace period will be available before the system is mandatory.

> but another page says we must have it to enter Finland and another one says mandatory to go to any Schengen country.

If you are using present tense to mean at the moment here, that's impossible for these statements to be true. ETIAS is *not* in operation right now for anyone for any country.

According to official [EU website](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/smart-borders/etias_en), ETIAS is expected to become operational by <del>the end of 2022</del>  <del>2024</del> 2025. Once it is operational, a grace period of six months is provided during which the relevant member states inform travellers and improve the awareness of the new system. During this period, the use of ETIAS will be optional.

An additional six-month grace period follows. During this period, ETIAS will be mandatory but exceptions will be made for the first time a traveller crosses the external border after the first grace period has ended. This limited grace period can be extended by the Commission for another six months. (Article 83, [Regulation (EU) 2018/1240](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32018R1240))

Comment: Now November 2023.

Comment: And now sometime in 2024: https://travel-europe.europa.eu/etias_en

Comment: @phoog I wonder which of ETIAS and REAL ID will be implemented first... But I assume ETIAS delays are caused by EES delays due to under-equipped ports of entries, which should be "easily" fixed.

Comment: Why would implementation of EES be a prerequisite for the implementation of ETIAS?  (And judging from the link posted above by Mark Johnson, I wouldn't be surprised to learn that they had belatedly realized that they'd given insufficient attention to the operation of the system at road crossings).

Comment: @phoog I don't think it had to be a technical prerequisite but from the things I've seen they were designed to be strongly integrated and it was sometimes mentioned that ETIAS is the 'final step' of the EES implementation, The provisions in the ETIAS regulation (2018/1240) also assume that EES is in operation.

Comment: "mandatory for third-country travellers": only certain ones, principally visa exempt short-term visitors.

Comment: @phoog Thanks, changed. And (un)expectedly, another delay...

Answer (score 3):

Update:

Implementation of ETIAS is postponed to May 2025.

Source: https://travel-europe.europa.eu/etias/faqs-etias_en

[image]

Source: https://www.forbes.com/advisor/ca/travel-insurance/travel-pass-etias-pushed-2025

[image]